TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tap') after moving index.html inside client folder in React project
I encountered an issue after restructuring my React project by moving the index.html file into a client folder. I started getting the following error when trying to run my development server:
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tap')
    at exports.tap (/path-to-project/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin/lib/util/plugin-compat.js:118:25)
    at new CacheSerializerFactory (/path-to-project/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin/lib/CacheSerializerFactory.js:94:18)
    at HardSourceWebpackPlugin.apply (/path-to-project/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin/index.js:219:36)
...

Here is a simplified version of my webpack.config.js where I suspect the issue might be:
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
const { propIf, isDevelopment } = require('webpack-config-utils');

module.exports = {
  // other configurations
  plugins: [
    propIf(isDevelopment(), new HardSourceWebpackPlugin()),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: "./src/assets/images/favicon.ico",
      meta: {
        buildStamp: (new Date()).toISOString()
      }
    }),
  ],
};

Here are the key packages and versions I'm using:
"webpack": "^5.95.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
"webpack-config-utils": "^2.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0",
"webpack-subresource-integrity": "^5.2.0-rc.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",

old folder structure
project-root/
│
├── src/
│   ├── assets/
│   └── other-src-files/
│
├── index.html
├── webpack.config.js
└── other-root-files/

New folder structure
project-root/
│
├── client/
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── src/
│   ├── assets/
│   └── other-client-files/
│
├── webpack.config.js
└── other-root-files/

The error started after I moved the index.html file inside the client folder from the root directory.
Is there a known solution for this issue? How can I fix this without downgrading Webpack?

What does your new folder structure look like? What did your old folder structure look like? Why do you think downgrading webpack will help with this issue?

@ScottZ Updated folder structure in question itself.

Paths are relative to the webpack file location. For instance the path to the favicon which was ./src/assets/images/favicon.ico in your old file directory will be ./client/assets/images/favicon.ico in your new folder setup.   It looks like template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html') should be modified to template: path.join(__dirname, 'client/index.html')
